# Is it possible to apply REGEX rules on already matched cases?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to create some rules in REGEX that applies over the already matched cases?


For example:
I have this string: `Mark Marcus Miami 36yo`
I need to match only: `Mark Marcus Miami`
I used `(.*)`  and it matches: `Mark Marcus Miami` 

I'm wondering if I can somehow apply another REGEX rule ON THE MATCHED CASE to eliminate the space at the end of my initial match. Someway to say: remove last character of all matches you found so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the full name could possibly end with a `36yo` or similar age term, and you don't want that term if it does appear, you could stop matching using a positive lookahead:

```
^(\w+(?: \w+)*)(?=\s+\w+$)
```

This pattern matches a series of names words, except for the last word term in the input.  Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/s9b8D3/2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that's not the case. Everything can be different except for the fact that `age is always at the end and is separated by a space`. Age can also be fully spelled in letters or the name could contain special characters or address containing number. Basically the perfect solution is to eliminate the last string separated by a space including the space in front of it

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu That's actually simpler than what I expected.  Just stop the matching by using a positive lookahead, q.v. my updated answer above.

Comment: That's great, it works perfect. Thanks for the solution, but still, is it possible what I asked in the title? To apply rules on already matched cases?
If I match `abc` from `abcdefg`, can I, somehow, remove `c` instead of not matching it from the beginning?

Comment: I have answered the question which was asked above AFAIK.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Actually that was an example, the actual question was: `I'm wondering if I can somehow apply another REGEX rule ON THE MATCHED CASES to eliminate the space....` but anyway, thanks

Comment: ...my answer does _not_ match the final space before the `36yo` term.  Check the demo.  If you can find an input where my answer fails, I'm happy to keep iterating with you.

Comment: Your answer is good, the solution works, but the question was actually `"Can you apply rules over already matched cases?"`.  For example, having the following string: `abcxx abc`. First request comes and I have to match the `xx ` (including the space). So I use `([a-z][a-z] )`. Then the request is to remove also the space. Can I apply `[a-z][a-z]` somehow to already matched case? That was the main question.
AGAIN, your solution works and solves the example problem, but doesn't fully answer the question

Comment: OK...now it is more clear.  Yes, you can use a _capture group_: `([a-z][a-z])\s+` ... this way, you _match_ the two characters and following whitespace, but you only _capture_ the two characters in `$1` (or `\1`, depending on your regex flavor).